# How to recognize that Excel is really closing in an XLL add-in?

Tags: excel, add-in, xll

According to MSDN, Excel will call xlAutoClose on an xll add-in, when the add-in is unloaded (be it because excel is closing or maybe the add-in is being removed manually).

Unfortunately xlAutoClose is also called when the user tries to close the spreadsheet, but then cancels when prompted to save their work.

According to the Excel Add-In dev documentation ("Financial Applications using Excel Add-in Development in C / C++"), when Excel is *really* closing, xlAutoClose will be followed by a call to xlAddInManagerInfo. Unfortunately I found it to be not true (tested both on 2007 and 2010 versions of Excel).

Is there any reliable way for an XLL add-in to distinguish between attempted spreadsheet close and actual spreadsheet close?

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: An XLL is just a DLL with a funky name, so if all else fails, you can check what happens with the unloading in `DllMain`. The usual caveats apply here: there's almost nothing you can do safely from within a `DllMain` other than internal cleanup, so if you still need to do something that relates to the user's data somehow, now would not be the time to do it.